# Flutter: Connecting to localhost:5001 with http package from local device doesn't work

Tags: flutter, dart

I have the following problem: I have a .NET API running on my local machine at https://localhost:5001. When I execute a request in Postman, it works totally fine, but when executing the same API call in Dart, it won't work.

In Postman https://localhost:5001 will respond with a 401 or a 200 Statuscode.

When I execute the exact same URL in Flutter, it will give me a timeout:
[Flutter Devtools](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UQp7w.png)

When using https://localhost:5001 in Flutter -> SocketException: OS Error: Connection refused, errno = 111, address = localhost, port = 41838

When using https://192.168.0.154:5001 in Flutter -> SocketException: OS Error: Connection timed out, errno = 110, address = 192.168.0.154, port = 44624

Im executing the following code:

````
    var response = await http.get(url);
    if(response.statusCode == 200) {
      print(response.body);
    }else{
      throw Exception('Failed to fetch');
    }```
````